# How can I make content of file as output of command?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, solaris, files

I have a file contain list of path now I want to execute command on each line example :-

```
file name : rawabdeh .......
command : command
```

file contains:-

```
path/no/1/
path/no/2/
path/no/3/
```

I want to do the following :

```
command path/no/1/
command path/no/2/
command path/no/3/
```

Comment: Does each line of your file contain multiple paths and do you want to run `command` on each of the multiple paths on every line ?

Comment: no no each line of file conten one path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace input-file, command and output-file as you require

`cat input-file | sed 's/^/command /' >output-file`

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
xargs -a "$filename" -n 1 command
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your request completely, but if you have a list of paths in a file and want to execute the same command on each line in $filename, then you should do:

```
xargs -n 1 command < $filename
```

Comment: `xargs -n 1 command <$filename` ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your request completely, but if you have a list of paths in a file and want to execute the same command on each LINE IN FILE